# Protected section: no matching function to call

Tags: c++

Can somebody tell my why this code doesn't work? I've got: no matching function for call to 'Child::Child()' error. How to put this child into protected section properly? :(

```
class Child
{
protected:
    int cAge;
public:
    Child(int c)
    {
        this->cAge=c;
    }
};

class Parent
{
protected:
    int pAge;
    Child child;
public:
    Parent(int d)
    {
        this->pAge=d;
    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: You have to initialize it in you constuctors member initializer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "protected section". You should use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to specify the constructor of class `Child` to be called:

```
class Parent
{
// ...
public:
    Parent(int d) : child(d)
//                ~~~~~~~~~~
    {
        this->pAge=d;
    }
};
```

Otherwise, the default constructor of `Child` (i.e. `Child::Child()`) will be tried to call, but it doesn't exist.